# Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

I am trying to execute a batch scripts around 450MB in size. As it cant be directly executed from SSMS, hence I tried using SQLCMD but I am getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\_> sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P ****  -I "D:\script.sql"
Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe.
Communication link failure
```

If I use the command with switch `-e` I get to see a long list of script statements before this error shows up, confirming the doubt it is due to large size of the script.

Some searching and i came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846954/sqlcmd-error-microsoft-sql-server-native-client-10-0-communication-link-fail) which says:

*Smaller files will run, but if the file is too big, you'll still receive this exception. The only solution I could find was to break the file containing the T-SQL commands into multiple smaller files.*

What I want to ask, is my error are pertains to the same issue? If yes, neither SSMS nor SQLCMD whats the way out for executing such large scripts.