# Executing large script file (1.7GB) on Microsoft SQL Server using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a generated script file with 1.7 GB size, I'm trying to run this script using the following `sqlcmd`

```
sqlcmd -m1 -S 192.168.100.10\SQLHQ -U sa -P 123456 -i "E:/VMS2008R2.sql"
```

When I run this line in CMD as administrator, the command take some time and give me no error, the database schema generated to database but without data and without any success or finished message!

**UPDATE**

When I run the command without `-m1` I got the following exception:

> TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> Communication link failure

Comment: Check your script to make sure there is a go after the sql statement that did not execute.

Comment: The script generated by the sql server.

Comment: Unless one can look at the script it is difficult to tell what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried with outputting option (`-o` IIRC) to see what's being output? Perhaps that will reveal something.

Comment: You got the answer [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42849815/6598234)

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal answer helped me. I had a 242 MB script with over 850K insert statements. I just modified the script by added a GO statement after every insert statement. So total number of lines became 1,700K. Then the sqlcmd utility successfully ran.